# Sending messages between two Androids over WiFi

Tags: android, tcp, wifi, whatsapp, viber

How is it possible to send messages between two Android phones using Wifi, like for example Viber and WhatsApp work. I am not sure what kind of sockets should I use. Can anyone explain me how it works and how can I send messages from any Wifi connected.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at the [Nearby Connections API](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/overview)